# How can I save a fine-tuned version of StableDiffusion on a Google Colab and then deploy on Sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-colaboratory, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers, stable-diffusion

I have a question about saving and deploying a fine-tuned StableDiffusion model with endpoints. I'm comfortable with the data science and ML side, but not so much with the ways in which models can be deployed for production.

**The scenario:** I have fine-tuned StableDiffusion using [this Colab script](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/diffusers/sd_textual_inversion_training.ipynb) (which needed a lot of debugging). The results are satisfactory, and I want to make it available for public querying.

**The ambition**: I'd like to create some endpoints that allow users to input some text data that will then be used to create text prompts.

**The problem**: I don't know how to save the trained model from the Colab. Neither do I know how to access the model where ever I might choose to host it.

**Effort so far**: [Amazon Sagemaker seems to offer functionality to do this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/realtime-endpoints-deployment.html). However, there's a lot of assumed knowledge in the documentation, and it's challenging to follow.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Save the model as a PyTorch model file, then follow [this](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frameworks/pytorch/get_started_mnist_deploy.html) to deploy the model to an endpoint.